# Creating a dual web/socket server with mongoose

Tags: c, websocket, webserver, mongoose-web-server

I'm trying to port an example I've built with Node.js, Express and Socket.io into mongoose -- but I'm having trouble getting the created server to respond to both WebSocket connections and generic HTTP requests.

I started by copying the [web_server](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/blob/master/examples/web_server/web_server.c) example from mongoose, which simply creates an HTTP server. In this example line 384 calls `mg_create_server(NULL, EV_HANDLER)` where `EV_HANDLER` is actually NULL -- so all HTTP requests to the server just map appropriately to the "document_root" as you would expect. **So far, so good.**

However, when I look at the various WebSocket examples that ship with mongoose, I see that the `mg_create_server(server, handler)` calls have an actual handler method defined -- something like this:

```
static int ev_handler(struct mg_connection *conn, enum mg_event ev) {
    switch (ev) {
        case MG_REQUEST:
            if (conn->is_websocket) {
                handle_websocket_message(conn);
                return MG_TRUE;
            } 
            else {
                mg_send_file(conn, "index.html", NULL);  // Return MG_MORE after!
                return MG_MORE;
            }
        case MG_WS_CONNECT:
            // New websocket connection. Send connection ID back to the client.
          conn->connection_param = calloc(1, sizeof(struct conn_data));
          mg_websocket_printf(conn, WEBSOCKET_OPCODE_TEXT, "id %p", conn);
          return MG_FALSE;
        case MG_CLOSE:
            free(conn->connection_param);
            return MG_TRUE;
        case MG_AUTH:
            return MG_TRUE;
        default:
            return MG_FALSE;
    }
}
```

In these examples, the `MG_REQUEST` case manually returns "index.html" for **any request** which is not coming from a WebSocket... great for the simple examples, but it doesn't help me understand how to host a website AND socket connections on the same server.

I tried simply porting the `ev_handler` method from the WebSocket examples into the "web_server" example, but the HTTP requests seem to just hang and never resolve.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with that :

1. Fix the example you have. Change this

   ```
   mg_send_file(conn, "index.html", NULL);
   return MG_MORE;
   ```

   to this

   ```
   return MG_FALSE;
   ```

   Don't forget to set "document_root" option.
2. Use fossa - this is a library by the same vendor (Cesanta). Fossa is a superset of Mongoose, with richer and more clear API. Fossa uses different events for plain HTTP and Websocket request. Here is an example: https://github.com/cesanta/fossa/blob/master/examples/websocket_chat/websocket_chat.c

Comment: Returning `MG_FALSE` seems to do the trick. I swear I tried that yesterday to no avail, but maybe I had been staring at the code too long :-) Thanks!